# Centering a piece of Text within a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position some text in the middle of a CSS box. i tired using top:20px; but this moved the whole but rather than the text. any idea how can i do this?

here is my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o1hosbj/)

```
div {
    background: #ff9600;
    background: rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.95);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 182, 78, 1), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 182, 78, 1), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 182, 78, 1), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

    <body>
        <div>text</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: used to padding-top:20px;  <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/4o1hosbj/1/">like this</a>

Comment: Add `padding-top: 20px;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to `div` - http://jsfiddle.net/zx3rzwzt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Example 1

---

something like: [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/3034/).

It uses the css of:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

which could be quite beneficial for you. :)

---

## Example 2

---

A more versatile way would be to use `span` like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/)

which uses:

```
   div {
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #123456;
    }

    span {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    
      line-height: normal;
    }
```

---

## Possible Alternative to (2)

---

A slight variation of the second example would be to treat the div like a table cell, so altering the above css to:

```
div {
  display: table;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
   
}
```

And so [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D4quh/) should also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to this**

**Remove this css in**

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

**add this css**

```
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
padding-top:20px;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4o1hosbj/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `padding` to move the text inside the box.

However, I think that you should create a tag (a box) especially for the text, and give it some css property to center this box in the center of the main div (the main box).

Answer (score 0):

Try this my code:

```
<div>
    <span class="vertical-text">
        TEXT
    </span>
</div>

    $('.vertical-text').each(function() 
    {
        parent_height = $(this).parent().height();
        $(this).parent().css(
        {
            'height': parent_height + 'px',
            'line-height': parent_height + 'px',
        });
        $(this).css(
        {
            'line-height': 'normal',
            'display': 'inline-block',
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Silon/caonccjx/